# why the gage pressure of a fluid is zero at locations where the HGL intersects the fluid?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pipelines, bernoulli

I have searched for answers to this, but so far I have not found any consistent answers. Please, may anyone help me understand this.
[image]

Comment: How do you calculate the pressure at a point (depth) in a fluid?

Comment: `weight density * depth`

Comment: But in the example of my question, `weight density * depth` does not give any intuition.

Comment: It's clear from the context that "HGL" must, in some sense, mean "local ambient pressure", but does anyone know what the initialism "HGL" actually stands for?

Comment: >_HGL must It's clear from the context that "HGL" must, in some sense, mean "local_ ambient pressure"_< @DanielHatton

I have not understood what you have said.